# Cut string in php

Tags: php, string

what i want is to make this in variable string in PHP:

```
 $Vstr =<img alt="" src="x.jpg" usemap="#xxx" /><map id="raster1" name="xxx">
    <area shape="rectangle" coords="53,50,355,181" /></map>
```

end result should be:

```
<map id="raster1" name="xxx">
<area shape="rectangle" coords="53,50,355,181" /></map>
```

i try to use explode() but not working
could you please help me?
thank you in advance!

Comment: $Vstr = '<img alt="" src="x.jpg" usemap="#xxx" /><map id="raster1" name="xxx"><area shape="rectangle" coords="53,50,355,181" /></map>'; echo $Vstr;

Comment: it gave me the wrong output. 
it should be 
<map id="raster1" name="xxx">
<area shape="rectangle" coords="53,50,355,181" /></map>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may do it with explode like :

```
<?php

$Vstr = '<img alt="" src="x.jpg" usemap="#xxx" /><map id="raster1" name="xxx">
    <area shape="rectangle" coords="53,50,355,181" /></map>';

$do = explode("/>",$Vstr,2);

echo $do[1];

?>
```

#### response to comments below :

It is because your browser is rendering the output as html it self. You can see it by checking the html source in browser.

use

```
echo htmlentities($do[1]);
```

or

set the content type as `text/plain`

Comment: it didnot return anything?

Comment: It is because your browser is rendering the output as html it self. You can see it by checking the html source in browser.

Comment: ah i didn't hink about it, thank you!